# How to I include extra bars in grouped bar charts in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, charts, dataset, chart.js

So, currently, I have a bar chart in ChartJS, which uses the database to make price comparisons between different companies for differently-sized items (all items are the same, only the size is different).

The database looked like this:

id, company, price_for_small, price_for_medium, price_for_large, country

1, "abcd" ,         20     ,        30       ,        40      ,  "USA"

... and so on.

I have 3 sizes, so until now the bar chart had 3 groups:

[image: Link to image: https://imgur.com/EDb0Fnh]

The user would select a country from a dropdown list and the chart would display a price comparison between the different companies for that particular country.

I was asked to do two things: Add a 4th size, which I did. And then add a new type of item to the first 3 sizes. So for example, instead of 1 item in 3 sizes, I have Item A and Item B, both of which come in small, medium and large, and A comes in extra large as well. I have successfully added them to the database and the pricing works right. I just need to add them to the charts.

Since too many charts would look cluttered, what I want to do is:
When the user is filling the form with country, item, size, etc.. I want the graph to show only the charts for the item the user selects. So if they select Item A, the charts show Item A in the 4 sizes for that particular country. If they select B, it shows the 3 sizes for B.

First, I tried just adding the new item as bars in the already existing charts, but it didn't work because of the dataset grouping. Now I'm trying to find a way to show different graphs depending on the item selected. Is this possible at all? Sorry, new to JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<canvas width="600" height="480"id="myChart"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
plotGraph();
       var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'bar',
           data: price_data,
           options: chartOptions
   }); 

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var company1_data, company2_data, company3_data, price_data, chartOptions;
//Function to plot the bar chart
function plotGraph(){
    company1_data = {
    label : 'Company 1',
    data: [req_comp1.small, req_comp1.medium, req_comp1_large, 
           req_comp1.extra_large],
    borderWidth: 0,
    yAxisID: "y-axis-prices"
};
```

---- Same with the other two companies -----

```
price_data ={
      labels: ["Small", "Medium", "Large", "Extra Large"],
      datasets: [company1_data, company2_data, company3_data]
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I have a real hard time understanding the exact need. Can you refine the question that what data you have, and what is expected output in a concise way? It's not that you have posted the question with insufficient information, I think it's me who can't understand it properly.